# calling java function in javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call java function from javascript function. I am getting below error in javascript function

> Packages is not defined.

below is my javascript function

```
            function trial(){
            try{
            var callclass = new Packages.com.subcontroller.Demo.javamethod(pass);
            alert(callclass);
            }catch(err)
            {
                alert(err.message);
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        }
```

Please help me resolve this error.

Comment: that's not a thing you can do natively.

Comment: Look into node's `child_process` module (nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)

Comment: @DanO i am trying to fetch one value processed by **javamethod(pass)**. can you please help me .

Comment: @junvar bro i don't know nodejs concept can you help me writing code ?

Comment: @rajan, No. there are better resources out there that will teach you much better than I can in a 500-char-limit comment. That's why I gave you a link.